# Angular resource posts data but not receiving by django view

Tags: python, angularjs, django, angular-resource

I have created an angular resource as

```
var services = angular.module('Services', ['ngResource']).
// SEND_REPLY_SMS
factory('SendSMS', ['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('/bulk-sms/reply/', null,
    {
        send: {method: 'POST'},
    }
);
}]);
```

I used it as

```
var data = $scope.data;
SendSMS.send({},data,
   function(data){
       console.log(data);
   },function(error){
       console.log(error);
   }
);
```

I have checked with console.log(data), data contains the data and the browser shows that the post request has submitted the data.

But When I receive it in django view, I can not get the data in django view and my django view is

```
class ReplySMSView(View):

    def post(self, request):
        data = request.POST.copy()
        print 'post data', request.POST # here data is not printed
        data = dict(data.items())
        return self.process(request, data)

    def get(self, request):
        data = request.GET.copy()
        print 'get data', request.GET # here data is not printed
        data = dict(data.items())
        return self.process(request, data)

    def process(self, request, data):
        dct = {}
        print data 
        model = IncomingMessage
        account = request.user.account
        contacts = data.get('contacts', '')
        contacts = contacts if contacts else get_contacts_by_filter(model, data)
        # TODO: get_contacts_by_filter is not working here for IncomingMessage
        message = data.get('message', '')
        identity = data.get('identity', '')
        if not contacts:
            dct['contacts'] = 'No contacts found.'
        if not message:
            dct['message'] = 'Message is required.'
        if not identity:
            dct['identity'] = 'Identity is required.'
        if dct:
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(dct), content_type='application/json')
        response = send_bulk_sms(contacts, message, identity, account, module='bulk')
        return HttpResponse(response)
```

I am not getting where is problem in this code ?

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS will post that data serialized into JSON, but django is expecting to receive form data. If you want to receive that data, you can change default behavior of AngularJS, fetch data not using POST, but rather request.body or you can use some third-party package, like [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to do job for you.

Answer (score 0):

When calling ajax, you recieve encoded json string in request body, so you need to decode it using python's json module to get python dict.
As django is a web framweork, it expect data from a form.

I really reccomend using this framework http://www.django-rest-framework.org/

Anyway, to get post data will be like this in your view:

```
(Pdb) request.POST
<QueryDict: {}>
(Pdb) import json
(Pdb) json.loads(request.body)
{u'operator': u'pepe', u'password': u'1234', u'transport': u'LUUAAA'}
```

---

```
import json
class ReplySMSView(View):

    def post(self, request):
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        print 'post data', request.POST # here data is not printed
        data = dict(data.items())
        return self.process(request, data)
```